# WEB API Authorization through group membership with JWT authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-graph-api

The WEB API application is authenticated using JWT token passed by the client app. Given the token from the client app I want to perform additional check to see if the user from the token belongs to a security group using GRAPH API and authorize access to the API based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please **note** that, if you want to authorize user through group membership you have to make use of **`Authorization Code Flow`** to acquire the token.

Make sure to change the settings in the **Portal** like below:

*Go to App Registration -> Your App -> Token Configuration -> Add Group Claim*

[image]

Go to Manifest and update **`"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"`** like below:

[image]

I tried to reproduce the same via Postman and generated token via **`Authorization Code Flow`** like below:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code

client_id:client_id
client_secret:client_secret
scope:scope
code:code
redirect_uri: redirect_uri
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, **Group IDs** are included like below:

[image]

You can check the below code sample to check if value of Group Name exists in Sessions or in User claims:

```cs
  public static bool CheckUsersGroupMembership(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, string GroupName, IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor)
  {
      bool result = false;
      if (HasOverageOccurred(context.User))
      {
          var groups = GetUserGroupsFromSession(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session);
          if (groups?.Count > 0 && groups.Contains(GroupName))
          {
              result = true;
          }
      }
      else if (context.User.Claims.Any(x => x.Type == "groups" && x.Value == GroupName))
      {
          result = true;
      }
      return result;
  }
```

To know more in detail, please **refer** below GitHub Blog for sample code:

[Azure active-directory-groupclaims:  .NET web app that uses Azure AD groups for authorization](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims)